# Payment Processor for Authorize.net Server Integration Method (SIM)?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

Has anyone implemented a CiviCRM payment processor that uses the Authorize.net SIM method? (http://developer.authorize.net/api/)

The [docs say](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Authorize.net+Configuration) that CiviCRM does not have support for this.

> At this time, CiviCRM only supports the Advanced Integration Method.

My reason for asking: the SIM method reduces our campus-policy compliance burden compared to the AIM method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone has submitted a patch to enable SIM support for auth.net. Might be beneficial for you to investigate and see how much work might be involved in adding this to the current auth.net codebase.